# .htaccess blocking access to the site

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an issue with htaccess that is blocking php script access.

this is the error message I receive when i load up the page:

> You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

When i remove the .htaccess file i can access index.php with no issues.

The same .htaccess file was working fine on a different hosting that i use.

My .htaccess file (EDIT: rearranged after suggestion by toopay)

```
RewriteEngine On
<Files .*>
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^photos.+$ thumbs.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.html$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

I did try to set the file priviledges to 644, 755, 777 and still not working with any settings.

Could you please help me and see what i have wrong, as this is the first time it is happening and the same .htaccess file is working fine on a different domain (folder) on the same hosting.

Comment: Turn on Rewrite engine logging and examine the output.

Comment: Couldn't your last 2 rewriterules just produce an infinite loop? Just a thought.

Comment: @Tomas it is not producing an infinite loop: the second last row is not parkising the (.) the last line is parsing .html files only, not images ect. (this last line is needed only because the site was static html previously -> this way we don't loose visitors: php will redirect afterwards properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution, the issue was really simple, i was missing a + before FollowSymLinks. Simple issue, few wasted hours to find the solution. The weirdest part is that the on the same hosting, different domain/folder it is working the same without the +... Anyway thank you for your help.

this is my final working code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^photos.+$ thumbs.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.html$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't there be problem with `<Files .*>`? I think this is a wildcard pattern so you should use just `<Files *>`.

Comment: It was not a problem with the <files .*> i didn't need that at all actually, put that only to make sure that it is not htacces that was blocking the files.

Answer (score -1):

The order of your htaccess, should be...

```
RewriteEngine On
<Files .*>
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^photos.+$ thumbs.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.html$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @toopay, i just tried this, but with no success. Same error.

Comment: -1: As long as your `RewriteEngine On` goes before your `RewriteRule`, it can be anywhere. It has no effect on other directives.